# Expressjs routing setup with nodejs and mongodb

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to expressjs and nodejs. I'm working on a MEAN app, and I'm facing issues setting up the routes for expressjs. I read about some methods online  but if I use them my app will become confusing, so can you suggest me a good blog, tutorial or video where I can learn to set up my app?

Basically I want to do some thing like this:

There will be one file which will be called every time: **index.js**. We will require one **routes.js** file in that, and in routes.js we will include all of our service files like **login.js, signup.js** etc., so that when any url encounters it then that particular code executes. The flow will be like:

- index.js
- routes.js
- File where the URL matches.

I'm confused about this setup.

Answer (score 2):

Using middleware you could do what you want , look at this example

**app.js**

```
var routes = require('routes')
app
 .use("/user",routes.user)
 .use("/other",routes.other)
```

**routes/index.js**

```
module.exports = {
  user : require(./user),
  other : require(./other)
}
```

**routes/user.js**

```
var router = require("express").Router()

router.get("/",function (req,res){
  // GET /user
})
.post("/",function (req,res){
  //POST /user
})

module.exports = router;
```

**routes/other.js**

```
var router = require("express").Router()

router.get("/",function (req,res){
  // GET /other
})
.post("/",function (req,res){
  //POST /other
})

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's actually quite simple.

First of all you need a file—let's call it `app.js`—in your main directory.

All the `app.js` needs to contain for a beginning is

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

// viewed at http://localhost:8080
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // send file to client
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

// code gets executed when you fire a post request at http://localhost:8080/login
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
    // execute code
    // verify user, authenticate, store user in session/token/cookie
    // return/send results/status
});

app.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
    // execute code
    // create user object, create database record, store user in session/token/cookie
    // return/send results/status
});

app.listen(8080);
```

You can easily source the routes out, so your app.js doesn't become too heavy and your application is more structured, but the code above should cover your needs for a start.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes I have tried code like that and it worked, but now how can I source the routes out, can you please provide a simple example for that also ?

Answer (score 0):

use this to for scaffolding
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html 
app.js  routes everything to one routes defining file.

```
app.use('/api',require('./routes/api/allRoutes'));

allRoutes.js has all route definitions with controllers definitions

var roleCtrl=require('../master/role');
router.route('/role').post(roleCtrl.create);
router.route('/role/:roleId?').get(roleCtrl.retrieve);
```

My role.js looks like this

```
    const {ObjectId} = require('mongodb');

    module.exports =roleObj=
        {

            collection: require(__basedir+'/config/config').clientName +'role',


            create: function (req, res) {

                var db = req.app.db;

                var role =
                    {
                        roleName: req.body.roleName,
                        documentStatus:req.body.documentStatus||null,          
                        auditTrail :[ {timeStamp:null , userID:null, userName:null , change:null } ]

                    };


                db.collection(roleObj.collection).insertOne(role).then(function(result)
                {
                    var response={_id:result.insertedId, message:"inserted", success:true};
                    res.send(response);
                });

            },


            retrieve: function (req, res) {

                var db = req.app.db;

                var input = {};

                if (req.params.roleId != undefined)
                   input['_id'] = ObjectId(req.params.roleId);

                db.collection(roleObj.collection).find(input).toArray(function (err, result) 
                {

                    if (result.length != 0) res.send(result);

                    else res.send("empty");

                });


            }



        }
```